Test case and Test plan updation email notification couldn't be stopped
I am trying to stop email notification for test case and test plan updation in Kiwi tcms. I tried to use below code alone in email.py (located under tcms/testcases/helpers and tcms/testplans/helpers) for both testcase and testplan helpers.
# -- coding: utf-8 --

def email_plan_update(plan):
return

But it doesn't stop email sending process for those actions. How to stop test case updation and test plan updation mail ?
Thanks in advance.
